# Need to implement a pyqtgraph code into a pyqt5 design code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i need help because i did a program with qtgraph and implement it into a class but it don't work and i don't see the problem

```css
# Import libraries
from numpy import *
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import serial

# Create object serial port
ser = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyUSB0",baudrate=230400,timeout=1) # configuration du port série

### START QtApp #####
app = QtGui.QApplication([])            # you MUST do this once (initialize things)
####################
pg.setConfigOption('background','w')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Signal from serial port", size = (1920,1080)) # creates a window

## droite
p = win.addPlot(title="Semelles Gauche")  # creates empty space for the plot in the window
p.setYRange(0,1000)
p.setLabel(axis='left', text='Pression(Pa)')
p.setLabel(axis='bottom', text='Temps')
color_blue = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255)
color_aqua = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 255)
color_red = QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)
color_black = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0)
color_green = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0)
pen_blue = pg.mkPen(color_blue, width=3)
pen_red = pg.mkPen(color_red, width=3)
pen_aqua = pg.mkPen(color_aqua, width=3)
pen_black = pg.mkPen(color_black, width=3)
pen_green = pg.mkPen(color_green, width=3)
curveTi = p.plot(pen = pen_blue)                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
curveTe = p.plot(pen = pen_red)
curveMi = p.plot(pen = pen_aqua)                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
curveMe = p.plot(pen = pen_black)
curveDt = p.plot(pen = pen_green)                       # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
##gauche

p1 = win.addPlot(title="Semelles Droite")
p1.setYRange(0,1000)
p1.setLabel(axis='left', text='Pression(Pa)')
p1.setLabel(axis='bottom', text='Temps')
color_blue1 = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255)
color_aqua1 = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 255)
color_red1 = QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)
color_black1 = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0)
color_green1 = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0)
pen_blue1 = pg.mkPen(color_blue, width=3)
pen_red1 = pg.mkPen(color_red, width=3)
pen_aqua1 = pg.mkPen(color_aqua, width=3)
pen_black1 = pg.mkPen(color_black, width=3)
pen_green1 = pg.mkPen(color_green, width=3)
curveTiD = p1.plot(pen = pen_blue)                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
curveTeD = p1.plot(pen = pen_red)
curveMiD = p1.plot(pen = pen_aqua)                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
curveMeD = p1.plot(pen = pen_black)
curveDtD = p1.plot(pen = pen_green) 



windowWidth = 500                    # width of the window displaying the curve
Ti = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series     
Te = linspace(1,0,windowWidth)
Mi = linspace(2,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series     
Me = linspace(3,0,windowWidth)
Dt = linspace(4,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series     
Ti1 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series     
Te1 = linspace(1,0,windowWidth)
Mi1 = linspace(2,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series     
Me1 = linspace(3,0,windowWidth)
Dt1 = linspace(4,0,windowWidth)
ptr = 0  
ptr1 = 0                    # set first x position

# Realtime data plot. Each time this function is called, the data display is updated
def update():
    global curveTi, curveTe, curveMi, curveMe, curveDt, ptr,ptr1, Ti, Te, Mi, Me, Dt, curveTiG, curveTeG, curveMiG, curveMeG, curveDtG, Ti1, Te1, Mi1, Me1, Dt1  
    Ti[:-1] = Ti[1:]  
    Te[:-1] = Te[1:]
    Mi[:-1] = Mi[1:]
    Me[:-1] = Me[1:]
    Dt[:-1] = Dt[1:]
    Ti1[:-1] = Ti1[1:]  
    Te1[:-1] = Te1[1:]
    Mi1[:-1] = Mi1[1:]
    Me1[:-1] = Me1[1:]
    Dt1[:-1] = Dt1[1:]  
     
    receive = ser.read(22)  #reception de 22 bytes 
    receivehex = receive.hex() # conversion en héxadecimal
    liste = str(receivehex)

##gauche
    if liste[2:3]=='0':
        print(liste)
        int_talonig = int(liste[6:9], 16)  # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
        print(liste[6:9])                  
        int_taloneg = int(liste[9:11], 16)# shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
        print(liste[9:11])
        int_millieuig = int(liste[11:14], 16) # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
        print(liste[11:14])                   
        int_millieueg = int(liste[14:16], 16)# shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
        print(liste[14:16])
        int_doigtg = int(liste[16:18], 16) # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
        print(liste[16:18])
        valueg = int_talonig               # read line (single value) from the serial port
        valueg1 = int_taloneg
        valueg2 = int_millieuig              # read line (single value) from the serial port
        valueg3 = int_millieueg
        valueg4 = int_doigtg 

        Ti[-1] = float(valueg)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
        Te[-1] = float(valueg1)
        Mi[-1] = float(valueg2)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
        Me[-1] = float(valueg3)
        Dt[-1] = float(valueg4)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
        
        ptr += 1                              # update x position for displaying the curve
        curveTi.setData(Ti)     
        curveTe.setData(Te)
        curveMi.setData(Mi)     
        curveMe.setData(Me)
        curveDt.setData(Dt)
                        # set the curve with this data
        curveTi.setPos(ptr,0)                   # set x position in the graph to 0
        curveTe.setPos(ptr,0)
        curveMi.setPos(ptr,0)                   # set x position in the graph to 0
        curveMe.setPos(ptr,0)
        curveDt.setPos(ptr,0) 

##droit
    if liste[2:3]=='1':
        print(liste)
        int_taloni = int(liste[6:9], 16)  # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
        print(liste[6:9])                  
        int_talone = int(liste[9:11], 16)# shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
        print(liste[9:11])
        int_millieui = int(liste[11:14], 16) # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
        print(liste[11:14])                   
        int_millieue = int(liste[14:16], 16)# shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
        print(liste[14:16])
        int_doigt = int(liste[16:18], 16) # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
        print(liste[16:18])
        value = int_taloni               # read line (single value) from the serial port
        value1 = int_talone
        value2 = int_millieui               # read line (single value) from the serial port
        value3 = int_millieue
        value4 = int_doigt              # read line (single value) from the serial port
        
        Ti1[-1] = float(value)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
        Te1[-1] = float(value1)
        Mi1[-1] = float(value2)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
        Me1[-1] = float(value3)
        Dt1[-1] = float(value4)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
        
        ptr1 += 1                              # update x position for displaying the curve
        curveTiD.setData(Ti1)     
        curveTeD.setData(Te1)
        curveMiD.setData(Mi1)     
        curveMeD.setData(Me1)
        curveDtD.setData(Dt1)       # set the curve with this data
                        
        curveTiD.setPos(ptr1,0)                   # set x position in the graph to 0
        curveTeD.setPos(ptr1,0)
        curveMiD.setPos(ptr1,0)                   # set x position in the graph to 0
        curveMeD.setPos(ptr1,0)
        curveDtD.setPos(ptr1,0)                   # set x position in the graph to 0               
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()    # you MUST process the plot now

### MAIN PROGRAM #####    
# this is a brutal infinite loop calling your realtime data plot
while True: update()

### END QtApp ####
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_() # you MUST put this at the end
```

into this

```css
# Import libraries
from numpy import *
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import serial

# Create object serial port
ser = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyUSB0",baudrate=230400,timeout=1) # configuration du port série

class  CustomWidget(pg.GraphicsWindow):
          

    pg.setConfigOption('background','w')
    pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
    windowWidth = 500                    # width of the window displaying the curve
    Ti = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series     
    Te = linspace(1,0,windowWidth)
    Mi = linspace(2,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series     
    Me = linspace(3,0,windowWidth)
    Dt = linspace(4,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series     
    Ti1 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series     
    Te1 = linspace(1,0,windowWidth)
    Mi1 = linspace(2,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series     
    Me1 = linspace(3,0,windowWidth)
    Dt1 = linspace(4,0,windowWidth)
    
    ptr = 0  
    ptr1 = 0  
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kargs):
        pg.GraphicsWindow.__init__(self, **kargs)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Scrolling Plots')
## droite
        
        p = self.addPlot(title="Semelles Gauche")  # creates empty space for the plot in the window
        p.setYRange(0,1000)
        p.setLabel(axis='left', text='Pression(Pa)')
        p.setLabel(axis='bottom', text='Temps')
        color_blue = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255)
        color_aqua = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 255)
        color_red = QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)
        color_black = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0)
        color_green = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0)
        pen_blue = pg.mkPen(color_blue, width=3)
        pen_red = pg.mkPen(color_red, width=3)
        pen_aqua = pg.mkPen(color_aqua, width=3)
        pen_black = pg.mkPen(color_black, width=3)
        pen_green = pg.mkPen(color_green, width=3)
        self.curveTi = p.plot(pen = pen_blue)                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
        self.curveTe = p.plot(pen = pen_red)
        self.curveMi = p.plot(pen = pen_aqua)                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
        self.curveMe = p.plot(pen = pen_black)
        self.curveDt = p.plot(pen = pen_green)                       # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
        ##gauche

        p1 = self.addPlot(title="Semelles Droite")
        p1.setYRange(0,1000)
        p1.setLabel(axis='left', text='Pression(Pa)')
        p1.setLabel(axis='bottom', text='Temps')
        color_blue1 = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255)
        color_aqua1 = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 255)
        color_red1 = QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)
        color_black1 = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0)
        color_green1 = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0)
        pen_blue1 = pg.mkPen(color_blue1, width=3)
        pen_red1 = pg.mkPen(color_red1, width=3)
        pen_aqua1 = pg.mkPen(color_aqua1, width=3)
        pen_black1 = pg.mkPen(color_black1, width=3)
        pen_green1 = pg.mkPen(color_green1, width=3)
        self.curveTiD = p1.plot(pen = pen_blue1)                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
        self.curveTeD = p1.plot(pen = pen_red1)
        self.curveMiD = p1.plot(pen = pen_aqua1)                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
        self.curveMeD = p1.plot(pen = pen_black1)
        self.curveDtD = p1.plot(pen = pen_green1) 



                  # set first x position

# Realtime data plot. Each time this function is called, the data display is updated
    def update(self):
        self.Ti[:-1] = self.Ti[1:]  
        self.Te[:-1] = self.Te[1:]
        self.Mi[:-1] = self.Mi[1:]
        self.Me[:-1] = self.Me[1:]
        self.Dt[:-1] = self.Dt[1:]
        self.Ti1[:-1] = self.Ti1[1:]  
        self.Te1[:-1] = self.Te1[1:]
        self.Mi1[:-1] = self.Mi1[1:]
        self.Me1[:-1] = self.Me1[1:]
        self.Dt1[:-1] = self.Dt1[1:]  
        
        receive = ser.read(22)  #reception de 22 bytes 
        receivehex = receive.hex() # conversion en héxadecimal
        liste = str(receivehex)
        print(liste)
    ##gauche
        if liste[2:3]=='0':
            print(liste)
            int_talonig = int(liste[6:9], 16)  # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
            print(liste[6:9])                  
            int_taloneg = int(liste[9:11], 16)# shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
            print(liste[9:11])
            int_millieuig = int(liste[11:14], 16) # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
            print(liste[11:14])                   
            int_millieueg = int(liste[14:16], 16)# shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
            print(liste[14:16])
            int_doigtg = int(liste[16:18], 16) # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
            print(liste[16:18])
            valueg = int_talonig               # read line (single value) from the serial port
            valueg1 = int_taloneg
            valueg2 = int_millieuig              # read line (single value) from the serial port
            valueg3 = int_millieueg
            valueg4 = int_doigtg 

            self.Ti[-1] = float(valueg)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
            self.Te[-1] = float(valueg1)
            self.Mi[-1] = float(valueg2)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
            self.Me[-1] = float(valueg3)
            self.Dt[-1] = float(valueg4)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
            
            self.ptr += 1                              # update x position for displaying the curve
            self.curveTi.setData(self.Ti)     
            self.curveTe.setData(self.Te)
            self.curveMi.setData(self.Mi)     
            self.curveMe.setData(self.Me)
            self.curveDt.setData(self.Dt)
                            # set the curve with this data
            self.curveTi.setPos(self.ptr,0)                   # set x position in the graph to 0
            self.curveTe.setPos(self.ptr,0)
            self.curveMi.setPos(self.ptr,0)                   # set x position in the graph to 0
            self.curveMe.setPos(self.ptr,0)
            self.curveDt.setPos(self.ptr,0) 

    ##droit
        if liste[2:3]=='1':
            print(liste)
            int_taloni = int(liste[6:9], 16)  # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
            print(liste[6:9])                  
            int_talone = int(liste[9:11], 16)# shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
            print(liste[9:11])
            int_millieui = int(liste[11:14], 16) # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
            print(liste[11:14])                   
            int_millieue = int(liste[14:16], 16)# shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
            print(liste[14:16])
            int_doigt = int(liste[16:18], 16) # shift data in the temporal mean 1 sample left
            print(liste[16:18])
            value = int_taloni               # read line (single value) from the serial port
            value1 = int_talone
            value2 = int_millieui               # read line (single value) from the serial port
            value3 = int_millieue
            value4 = int_doigt              # read line (single value) from the serial port
            
            self.Ti1[-1] = float(value)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
            self.Te1[-1] = float(value1)
            self.Mi1[-1] = float(value2)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
            self.Me1[-1] = float(value3)
            self.Dt1[-1] = float(value4)                 # vector containing the instantaneous values      
            
            self.ptr1 += 1                              # update x position for displaying the curve
            self.curveTiD.setData(self.Ti1)     
            self.curveTeD.setData(self.Te1)
            self.curveMiD.setData(self.Mi1)     
            self.curveMeD.setData(self.Me1)
            self.curveDtD.setData(self.Dt1)       # set the curve with this data
                            
            self.curveTiD.setPos(self.ptr1,0)                   # set x position in the graph to 0
            self.curveTeD.setPos(self.ptr1,0)
            self.curveMiD.setPos(self.ptr1,0)                   # set x position in the graph to 0
            self.curveMeD.setPos(self.ptr1,0)
            self.curveDtD.setPos(self.ptr1,0)                   # set x position in the graph to 0                   # you MUST process the plot now
        
### MAIN PROGRAM #####    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = CustomWidget()
    w.show()
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

i take the information from the serial(bytes) and want to put 2 graphics with 5 curves, and i want to put it into a program with qtdesigner so can anyone help me pls to résolve my problem?

Comment: Two things, 1) could you please reconstruct your example so that it uses a function or random numbers instead of data from a serial port to make it easier for others to see the desired behavior, 2) could you describe what the problem is?  What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: hi the 2nd code don't show the curves i don't know why and the data in the plots you can replace it by int values

Comment: the code show up the graph but don't show the plots is like he is stack somewhere but idk why

Comment: One of your stated goals is to have a pyqtgraph plot in a Qt Designer layout. To do this, I place a QGraphicsView inside my Designer layout and then promote it to a PlotWidget. In your code, you need `from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget`. If you search for "plotwidget" in the [examples](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#examples) application they have some sample code that uses PlotWidget.

Comment: _Specifically_, what does "don't work" mean?

Comment: Its only that i don"t know exactly  how to put my pyqtgraph inside a qt designer, i saw that first of all i have to do it with a class like the 2nd program and i wanted to know why the program don't show the curves inside the plot that i created

Comment: when i create the QgraphicView inside QT designer how exactly i implement my code in the app? i convert the ui file into python then how do i put it inside all my code?

Answer (score 0):

I left out an important detail in promoting a widget in Designer in my comment. Normally when you type in a class name, Designer autofills the header file with `<lower case class name>.h`. In this case it would be `plotwidget.h`. But you want to edit the header file to be `pyqtgraph.h`

Here's a short example.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication)
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget

form = uic.loadUiType('pw.ui')[0]

class mainWindow(QMainWindow, form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ~ super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.show()

    def on_button_clicked(self):
        p1 = self.plotwidget1.plot()
        xdata = list(range(10))          # 0 to 9
        ydata = list(range(0, 100, 10))  # 0 to 90 by 10
        p1.setData(x=xdata, y=ydata)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
    pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
    pg.setConfigOption('antialias', True)
    app = QApplication([])
    a=mainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

pw.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0" colspan="2">
     <widget class="PlotWidget" name="plotwidget1"/>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="button">
      <property name="text">
       <string>push me</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>675</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PlotWidget</class>
   <extends>QGraphicsView</extends>
   <header>pyqtgraph.h</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: itried to assamble all my code in your exemple  but the curves don't show their serlves. You agreed that the customisations and plot have to be in init? and the other have to be on another function update but how can i say that the update run like a loop?

Comment: If you are already committed to using Qt, I would suggest you look into using [QSerialPort](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) too. One of the big advantages of QSerialPort is that it has a [readyRead signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) that fires whenever there is data waiting on the serial port. You can connect this signal to your update function. Otherwise, you typically need a QTimer to fire and periodically check your PySerial port.